# CVS cvs command exited with exit-status 1

Tags: cvs

I'm trying to revive a old project from a CVS server. To do this, I have had to pull the CVS server data image from backup and install CVS from scratch.

When trying to login to the CVS server, I get:

```
pi$ export CVSROOT=:pserver:ian@localhost:/data/cvs
pi$ cvs login
Logging in to :pserver:ian@localhost:2401/data/cvs
CVS password: 
cvs [login aborted]: reading from server: Connection reset by peer
```

Checking syslog:

```
Apr  7 05:03:14 raspberrypi cvsd[14833]: connection from 127.0.0.1 55155
Apr  7 05:03:14 raspberrypi cvsd[14833]: cvs command exited with exit-status 1
```

I changed the permissions on the directories to the user and group (cvsd:cvsd) given in

```
/etc/cvsd/cvsd.conf
```

which contains:

```
pi$ cat /etc/cvsd/cvsd.conf | egrep -v "^#.*|^$"
RootJail /var/lib/cvsd
Uid cvsd
Gid cvsd
Nice 1
Umask 027
PidFile /var/run/cvsd.pid
MaxConnections 10
Log syslog info
Listen * 2401
Repos /data/cvs
```

The data is under:

```
/data/cvs
```

The user and password is correct as given in the file

```
/data/cvs/CVSROOT/passwd
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the answer. At some point after I stopped using CVS regularly, the server was changed to use RootJails by default. The config file

```
/etc/cvsd/cvsd.conf
```

was upgraded, and the line

```
RootJail /var/lib/cvsd
```

was added to the configuration. This means that the data path

```
/data/cvs
```

became **relative** to the RootJail.

Quick fix. Change

```
RootJail /var/lib/cvsd
```

to

```
RootJail none
```

(Or just move the data), and restart CVS.